# How do you say “Turnover” in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

> Governor General Simon de Anda y Salazar and his defenders entered
>   Manila to accept the **turnover** of the city of Manila from the British
>   forces

I am translating this as:

> El Gobernador Simón de Anda y Salazar y sus protectores entraron a
>   Manila para aceptar  el `movimiento` de la ciudad de Manila de las
>   fuerzas inglesas.

What is the right translation for the word `turnover`? My dictionary says `el movimiento` and `movimiento de personal`.

Comment: For words like this, you need to practice translating the concept, not the word.

Answer (score 6):

In this context, I think the right translation of *turnover* would be *devolución*. And I would add *por parte de* to make the sentence clearer:

> El Gobernador Simón de Anda y Salazar y sus protectores entraron a
>   Manila para aceptar la **devolución** de la ciudad de Manila **por parte de**
>   las fuerzas inglesas.

I am not too comfortable about the translation of *defenders* in this sentence, but this goes out of the scope of the question.

Comment: What does " por parte de" mean in this context?

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 It means that it is *las fuerzas inglesas* who do *la devolución*. Yo could have written just *por* instead of *por parte de*, but writing just *de* is not correct in this case.

Answer (score 5):

The word I would use is "entregar," since it has the connotations of to "hand in," or "surrender."

It does not have the usual connotations of "turnover," which might be rotacion or movimiento.

So it would be:

> El Gobernador Simón de Anda y Salazar y sus protectores entraron a
>   Manila para aceptar la entrega de la cuidad por parte de las
>   fuerzas inglesas.

One can't "move" a city. But one can transfer the "keys" to the city, and thereby surrender (entregar) it.

Comment: Yes.  "para aceptar la entrega de la ciudad de Manila"

Comment: I'd also use "entregar", and agree with the connotation. I've edit the answer to include the conjugated verb

Answer (score 1):

> El Gobernador Simón de Anda y Salazar y sus protectores entraron a
>   Manila para aceptar la entrega de la ciudad de Manila por parte de las
>   fuerzas inglesas.

Answer (score 0):

Turnover lo he oído cuando hay una rotación o renovación del personal, ya sea de una empresa (employee turnover) u otro.

[Ejemplo](http://www.policechiefmagazine.org/magazine/index.cfm?fuseaction=display_arch&article_id=697&issue_id=92005):

> Police departments across the country are reporting increased rates of staff turnover. Many agencies are spending enormous amounts of resources on recruiting, selecting, and training new employees. At the same time, they are unable to make progress because they are losing experienced officers to other employers.

In your case it is due to the British invasion on Manila and the resistance from natives with Simón de Anda. Enemy surrendered at 1874 according to Wikipedia an many other sources:

> La Guerra de Siete Años terminó con el Tratado de París (1763), firmado el 10 de febrero de 1763. En el momento de la firma del tratado, los firmantes no eran conscientes de que Manila había sido tomada por los británicos y, en consecuencia cayó bajo la disposición general de que todas las demás no se disponga lo contrario será devuelto a la corona española.14 > Después Arzobispo Rojo falleció en enero de 1764, el ejército británico finalmente reconoció Simón de Anda y Salazar como el legítimo gobernador de Filipinas, enviándole una carta dirigida al la Real Audiencia y Capitanía General Gobernadora, tras lo cual Anda acordó un armisticio a condición de que las fuerzas británicas se retiraron de Manila en marzo.

So your sentence or translation can be...if your sentence is [that one](http://tumblr.malacanang.gov.ph/post/51775954581/today-in-history-in-1764-simon-de-anda-y-salazar):

> TODAY IN HISTORY: In 1764, Simón de Anda y Salazar and his defenders enter Manila to accept the turnover of the City of Manila from the British forces.

Spanish:

> **En 1764, Simón de Anda y Salazar junto a sus defensores/tropas entro (en Manila) como legitimo gobernador de Filipinas en la ciudad de Manila tal y como acordaron con las fuerzas británicas.**

I think this would be a good translation. The turnover makes sense here because:

*From wikipedia*

> El 2 de noviembre de 1762, Dawsonne Drake de British East India Company asumió el cargo como gobernador británico de Manila.

So there is a 'rotación/cambio/renovación del personal' in this case as 'Gobernador de Manila' to Simón de Anda in 1764 from Manuel Antonio Rojo del Río, and from Dawsonne Drake in the british side of Manila.

Another option can be *relevo* de gobernador.

[Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocupaci%C3%B3n_brit%C3%A1nica_de_Manila)

Answer (score 0):

Yo entiendo

> El Gobernador Simón de Anda y Salazar y sus protectores entraron en Manila para aceptar de vuelta la ciudad de Manila por parte del dominio británico.

Hay palabras que no tienen el mismo significado o connotación en Español cuando las traduces literalmente. Por lo menos yo, cuando trato de traducir algo, lo que hago es cojer la idea en ingles y reproducirla en Español, no las palabras.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here will be: Cesión

> El gobernador Simón de Anda y Salazar y sus defensores entraron a Manila para aceptar la cesión de la ciudad en pos de las fuerzas británicas.

A turnover in any turn based game, like chess is the fact to pass the turn to your rival, this on spanish could be translated like "ceder el turno" wich in a more warlike context probably will sound better just as "cesión".

I wonder if the use of turnover in english in this context is something usual or merely a stylish resource from the author.

Answer (score -3):

The right translation on your context is "pérdida"

> El governador Simón de Anda y Salazar y sus defensores entraron a Manila para aceptar la pérdida de la ciudad en pos de las fuerzas británicas.

Comment: I don't know who evaluates the right answers and give my answer bad qualification, because that's the best translation in spanish from Spain.